# How to delete all lines from a CSV file containing an exact match of a search term?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a CSV file like this:

```
text,0
more text,2
some more text,100
```

I need to delete any line containing only `0` in the second column, e.g., the output of the above would be:

```
more text,2
some more text,100
```

How can I delete all lines from a CSV with an exact match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's your last field, grep will do the trick:

```
grep -v ',0$'
```

If not, and your fields don't contain `,`, use awk:

```
awk -F , '{if ($2!='0') print}'
```

If it's even more complex use python or ruby with a CSV parser.

Answer (score 3):

A simple sed solution...

```
sed /,0$/d
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an inline edit to your file you could try the following. REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO ATTEMPTING ANY INLINE EDIT. (Will delete lines that contain a match)

```
sed -i "s/.*match.*//g" /yourfile.csv
```

To delete any blank lines within your file. (REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO ATTEMPTING ANY INLINE EDIT.)

```
sed -i "/^$/d" /yourfile.csv
```

**For OS X** you can try the following (REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO ATTEMPTING ANY INLINE EDIT.)

```
sed -i '' "s/.*match.*//g" /yourfile.csv
sed -i '' "/^$/d" /yourfile.csv
```

Comment: NOTE: I have used double quotes in case you may be using a variable within the sed command.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F, '$2' file
```

Comment: Note that this will also delete lines with an empty `$2`